# add JSON objects to an array which is to be used as a list

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list, object

My aim is to add a JSON object based on certain conditions to an array which is then to be used to construct a WINJSList. I'm really struggling with accessing the elements of the list OR array after I have used the array.push method. I wanted to access these elements to ensure I am doing the addition right. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have the following code

```
    var names_Array = new Array;

                   var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);

                    if (condition) {

                        if (condition) {
                            names_List.push({ name: "Joe Dowling", image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", ClientID: "1234" });
                        }
                        else if (condition) {
                            names_List.push({ name: "Esteban Flamenco ", image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", ClientID: "6666" });
                        }
                        else if (condition) {
                            names_List.push({ name: "Plain Jane ", image: "image/Plain Jane.png", ClientID: "0000" });
                        }

console.log(names_Array);
console.log(names_Array[0]);
console.log(names_List);
console.log(names_List[0]);
```

I also tried:

```
var names_Array = new Array; if (condition) {

                    if (condition) {
                        names_Array.push({ name: "Joe Dowling", image: "image/Joe Dowling.png", ClientID: "1234" });
                    }
                    else if (condition) {
                        names_Array.push({ name: "Esteban Flamenco ", image: "image/Esteban Flamenco.png", ClientID: "6666" });
                    }
                    else if (condition) {
                        names_Array.push({ name: "Plain Jane ", image: "image/Plain Jane.png", ClientID: "0000" });
                    }
var names_List = new WinJS.Binding.List(names_Array);
```

In the console I either get undefined or [object object]

Answer (score 1):

I think you should just declare your names_Array like so:

`var names_Array = [];`

Also, using a switch statement would help to clear some confusion, I don't think there is a closing brace for the first if statement (from my observation)

Comment: @ Samuel Monday I had tried that way of declaring the array too but it didn't work. I actually got it working when I included the script in the html in script tags instead of saying the script source was another file. So, something weird was going on there. Thanks!